# How to play s video stored on the web by HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

How is it possible to play a video stored on the web through HTML5?
For example, this video http://www.cybertechmedia.com/samplevideos.html

And I need to play it. How can I refer to it?

I thought:

```
var video = getDocumentById('videoPreview');
video.myFile = ???;
```

What shall I refer to myFile with? Or shall I use something else?

Comment: It's not `video.myFile`, it's `video.src`

Comment: And it takes the path? "http://..... .wmv" ?

Comment: Yes and no. Your browser will not support WMV. Either OGG or MP4 but support isn't very compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [chapter on video](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/video.html) in Dive into HTML 5 for the long answer.

The short answer is:

> How is it possible to play a video stored on the web through HTML5?

In supporting browsers, use the `<video>` element and set the `src` to point to the URI

> For example, this video http://www.cybertechmedia.com/samplevideos.html

But not those videos as they aren't stored in formats that browsers support.

Comment: That's pretty complicated. Isn't there a simple tutorial with a sample code?

Comment: The subject is complicated. A simple tutorial (which is the line of my answer that appears immediately after the first quote) will miss out a lot of stuff that you need to do to make sure the video is going to work.